# Why can't I delete a row in Postgresql-Pgadmin when I already followed the format?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, quoted-identifier

I have a table `Department` with 2 columns, `DEPT_CODE` the PK and `DEPT_NAME` and both have data types `name`. I inserted:

```
INSERT INTO public."Department"("DEPT_CODE", "DEPT_NAME")
VALUES ('CIS', 'Computer Info Systems');
```

then I want to delete it so I wrote:

```
DELETE FROM public."Department"
    WHERE 'DEPT_CODE' = 'CIS';
```

This didn't delete the row (I used the delete script provided by pgadmin). If I don't use quote for the `'DEPT_CODE'`, it gave an error:

```
ERROR:  column "dept_code" does not exist
LINE 2:  WHERE DEPT_CODE = 'CIS';
```

Idk what to do. Every tutorial I see seemed to be able to delete just fine, why not mine? This is my first time using pgadmin-postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) identifiers (column & table names) need to be enclosed in double quotes. Single quotes are only for string [constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).

And because you used the dreaded double quotes for the table and column names when you created the table, you now need to use them always:

```
DELETE FROM public."Department"
WHERE "DEPT_CODE" = 'CIS';
       ^               ^
       | column name   | string constant
```

---

It's [**strongly** recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) to avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers completely. So never use double quotes when you **create** tables, then you never need to use them when working with the tables